# Safari Keyframes not working

Tags: css, safari

Ok, so I've been working on an image slider which works perfect on all browsers except safari (on apple device and on windows safari) I can't seem to work out why its not working.

Anybody got any ideas?

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

#slider { overflow: hidden; }
#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly does it do on Safari (or doesn't do for that matter) for which you are saying that 'it does not work perfectly' there?

Comment: add prefix `-webkit-animation`

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it works perfect now, its a simple pure css image slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari requires the prefixed `-webkit-animation` property.

```
#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0;
-webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Safari 9 (released September 2015) no-longer requires the `-webkit-` prefix. Usage of Safari 8.x and earlier is under 1% of all browsers, according to CanIUse.com now.